# What is the Joint Probability Density Function (PDF) of Two Dependent Continuous Random Variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let 'X' and 'Y' be two **dependent** continuous random variables whose marginal PDFs ($f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$) are known. Then, how can we find their joint PDF i.e., $f_{XY}(x,y)$ . Is there any method to calculate this ?

Comment: No. You cannot do this  without further information.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.
If the two random variables were independent then their joint PDF would be $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

In in the case of dependent random variables we cannot infer anything, not even that the joint distribution is continous.
For instance, let $X$ be a random variable following Uniform Continous Distribution on $[0,1]$ and let's define $Y=1-X$. Then, it can be proven that $X$ and $Y$ are not jointly continous.